# Minkowski sums of convex and bounded sets

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

I am trying to prove the following.

**Question.** Suppose $A,B,C\subset E^n$ and that
$$A+C \subset B+C.$$

If $A,B$ are both convex, $B$ is closed, $C$ is bounded, show that $A\subset B$.

So far I have done the following. Where am I going wrong?

**Proof.** Let $a\in A$. Then,
$$a+c_0\in A+C,\ \forall c_0\in C$$ 
$$ \Rightarrow a+c_0 \in B+C, \forall c_0\in C$$
$$ \Rightarrow a+c_0 = b+c_1,\ \text{for some}\ b\in B,c_1\in C.$$

For every line $\lambda a_0 + (1-\lambda)a_1 + c_0,\ 0\leq \lambda \leq 1,$ that contain $a$, there must exist a closed line $\lambda b_0 + (1-\lambda)b_1 + c_1, 0\leq \lambda \leq 1,$ that contains $b$ and $\lambda a_0 + (1-\lambda)a_1 + c_0$. Now, since $C$ is bounded $a$ is contained in $\lambda b_0 + (1-\lambda)b_1\in B$.

Comment: Consider $E = \mathbb{R}$, $A = \{0\}$ and $B = C = (0,1)$. Then $A+C = (0,1)$ and $B+C = (0, 2)$. So the hypotheses are all satisfied except for $B$ being closed. If you take $a = 0$, $c_0 = 1/2$, $b=3/8$ and $c_1 = 1/8$, you have $a+c_0 = b+c_1$. Yet $a \not \in B$. The 'line' $\lambda a_0 + (1- \lambda)a_1 + c_0$ is the singleton $\{1/2\}$. Of course here you can find a line $\lambda b_0 + (1- \lambda)b_1 + c_1$ which contains both $b$ and $1/2$, say with $b_0 = 1/4$ and $b_1 = 1/2$; $a$ isn't in the line $\lambda b_0 + (1-\lambda)b_1$, but is in $\lambda b_0 + (1-\lambda)b_1 + c_1 - c_0$.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose on the contrary that $A \not \subset B$. Then there exists $a \in A$ such that $a \not \in B$. Since $B$ is closed and convex and so is $\{a\}$, from some version of the geometric Hahn-Banach theorem, there are a real number $r$ and a nonzero linear map $l : E^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $l(a) > r$ and $l(B) \le r$. Set $\epsilon = l(a)-r > 0$.

Since $C$ is bounded, since $l$ is linear and since we work in finite dimension $n$, the number $M := \sup_{c \in C} l(c)$ is finite. Observe that for $x \in B+C$, $l(x) \le r + M$. Consider $c_0 \in C$ such that $l(c_0) > M - (\epsilon/2)$. Then by the linearity of $l$,
$$l(a+c_0) = l(a) + l(c_0) > r + \epsilon + M - (\epsilon/2) = r + M + (\epsilon/2) > r+M \, .$$
It follows that $a + c_0 \not \in B+C$, which contradicts the assumption that $A+C \subset B+C$. Notice that we did not use the convexity of $A$.

---

The geometric Hahn-Banach theorem used above is a rather accessible statement in finite dimensions. Let $B \subset E^n$ be a closed convex set and $\{a\} \in E^n \setminus B$.

Since convexity is a property invariant under changes of equivalent norms, and since all norms on a finite dimensional space are equivalent, we can without loss of generality consider the strictly convex norm $\|-\|$ on $E^n$ associated to the 'usual' Euclidean scalar product on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $d = d(a, B) = \mathrm{inf}_{b \in B} \, d(a,b)$ where $d(x,y) := \|y-x\|$; we claim that this infimum is achieved. Indeed, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $b_n \in B$ be such that $d(a,b_n) \le d + (1/n)$. (Observe interestingly that this relies on the countable axiom of choice, but this is a weaker axiom than the usual axiom of choice and it is somewhat more 'intuitive' than Zorn's lemma...) Since the sequence $\{b_n\}$ lies inside the bounded closed (hence compact) set $B \cap \bar{B}(a, 1)$, a subsequence of it converges say towards $b_0 \in B$. Of course, $d = d(a,b_0)$.

We claim that $b_0$ is the unique element in $b \in B$ such that $d = d(a,b)$. Assuming otherwise, let $b_1 \in B \setminus \{b_0\}$ satisfy $d = d(a,b_1)$. Since $B$ is convex, the segment $b_{\lambda} = \lambda b_0 + (1- \lambda) b_1$ with $\lambda \in [0,1]$ lies in $B$. Hence for $\lambda \in (0,1)$
$$ d \le d(a, b_{\lambda}) = \| b_{\lambda} - a \| = \| \lambda (b_0 - a) + (1- \lambda)(b_1 - a)  \| < \lambda d(a,b_0) + (1- \lambda) d(a,b_1) = d$$
where the strict inequality holds since the euclidean norm is strictly convex. This is a contradiction, hence $b_0$ is unique.

Let $v = a-b_0$ and $w = (b_0 + a)/2$. Consider the linear map $l : E^n \to \mathbb{R} : x \mapsto x \cdot v$ and set $r := l(w)$. Then $l(a) > r$ and $l(b_0) < r$. Moreover $l(B) < r$, in fact $\mathrm{max}_{b \in B} l(b) = l(b_0)$; this follows from the fact that the hyperplane $[x:l(x) = l(b_0)]$ is the tangent plane at $b_0$ to the sphere $\partial B(a, d)$. Indeed, for $x \in \bar{B}(a,d)$, $l(x) \ge l(b_0)$ with equality if and only if $x=b_0$. If there were to exist $b_1 \in B$ such that $l(b_1) > l(b_0)$, a part of the segment joining $b_0$ to $b_1$ would lie strictly inside $\bar{B}(a,d)$ hence contradicting the definition of $b_0$.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've seen a similar proof before. I was trying to come up with maybe something simpler without using Hahn-Banach theorem.

Comment: @Teodorism I understand your point. But the Hahn-Banach theorem is an important part of convex geometry; the geometric version used above is intuitively appealing, and it has a rather compelling proof in finite dimensions (in the sense that it resembles many usual arguments in geometry and topology). Moreover, since the statement is false if we drop the assumption that $B$ is closed, I am led to believe that any proof of the statement would rely one way or another on the possibility to 'strictly separate' $B$ from $\{a\}$, which is Hahn-Banach in disguise.